# Understanding plot for stats::predict

Tags: r, forecasting, prediction-interval

I created a time series for 15 years (in each year 123 days), and I created a forecast using stats::predict for the next 5 years.

```
temps_ts <- ts(data = temps_vec, frequency=123, start=1996)
temp_HW_model <- HoltWinters(temps_ts, 
                         alpha=NULL, beta=NULL, 
                         gamma=NULL, seasonal = "additive")

temp_forecast=stats::predict(temp_HW_model, n.ahead = 615, prediction.interval = TRUE )
plot(temp_forecast)
```

My concern is the interpretation of plot, according my understanding there is no change or variation in the data, but the upper and lower levels present variations, that is for the period of the time in evaluation or it means something else?

[image]

Comment: The top panel is the forecasted/predicted/fit time series and the bottom two panels are the associated upper and lower confidence interval bounds. As you forecast farther and farther out, the associated uncertainty with those forecasts increases because the data used for the model get less and less relevant to the forecast. As a result, your confidence interval bounds will get wider over time.

Comment: @EmmaJean Thank you very much!

Comment: @EmmaJean: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it. Incidentally, the plot shows *prediction* intervals, not *confidence* intervals, [there is a difference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info).

Comment: @StephanKolassa Sure! Posted and changed the language to prediction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top panel is the forecasted/predicted/fit time series and the bottom two panels are the associated upper and lower prediction interval bounds. As you forecast farther and farther out, the associated uncertainty with those forecasts increases because the data used for the model get less and less relevant to the forecast. As a result, your prediction interval bounds will get wider over time.